# In Java, how do I read two data types, char and int from a single .dat file?

Tags: java, file, parsing, key-value-store

As a part of a larger assignment,I have been instructed to read in a .date file path entered by the user that contains a the following data.

```
e 2
b 1
a 3
h 5
c 4
```

After running through a linked list function, the list should read "beach" in the console. Here is the code snippet where I'm struggling.

```
     do {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the secret file name: ");
        String filename = scnr.nextLine();
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter("\\/");

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {


            //String line = reader.nextLine();
            //int val = reader.readInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Ready to play? (no to quit): ");
        userDecision = scnr.nextLine();

    } while (!userDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
```

I'm thinking that it would be better to parse the file as characters into strings but I don't know how to do that.Yes, I'm aware this is a stupid question.

Comment: Read it as a string, using `reader.next()`. Parse as appropriate.

Comment: why `.useDelimiter("\\/")`? this is not the delimiter in shown file - will *confuse*  `next()` or `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

As Andy wrote, `next()` is made to read a string, and `nextInt()` reads an integer number.

`nextLine()` reads the remainder from the current position until end of line. After the integer number, the remainder is the line-break, which explains why your attempt did not work as expected.